# My path of attachments in nodeMailer is not working (Sails app)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, email-attachments, nodemailer

I'n building a web app by using Sails framework.
I am unable to attach an image in email.

Here is my mail options,

```
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        html: html,
        attachments: [{
            filename: "login-logo.png",
            filePath: "./assets/images/login-logo.png",
            cid: "logo-mail"
        }]
    };
```

and my ejs where I attach an image,

```
<img src="cid:logo-mail" />
```

At filePath I try

- filePath: "./assets/images/login-logo.png"
- filePath: "/assets/images/login-logo.png"
- filePath: "/images/login-logo.png"
- filePath: "./images/login-logo.png"

But didn't work.

I don't know how to fix it. I really need some help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to expand upon "but didn't work". What do you mean? Are you sure their is no attachment on the email? Also what version of everything are you using? and are you using the current or depreciated node-mailer?

Comment: [The fine manual](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachments) suggests that `filePath` isn't a valid property (`path` is, though).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this works for me:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    html: html,
    attachments: [{
                 filename: 'Logo.png',
                 filePath: 'assets/images/Logo.png',
                 cid: 'logo'
                 }]
    }
```

I used nodemailer 0.7.1